# Setting download path to %appdata% and further

Tags: java, appdata

In a download (Java) script can you set the location to `%appdata%`, `%home%`, ect.? I've tried adding this the script in many different ways but all I come up with are errors. Do I need launch a `.bat` file before hand to set the directory, `cd` and everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the path to an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) using [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) (no `.bat` script required):

```
File dir = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA"), "DataFolder");
```

To make sure the folder is created:

```
if (!dir.exists())
{
    try
    {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To make a file in the folder and make sure it is created:

```
File file = new File(dir, "log.txt");
if (!file.exists())
{
    try
    {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```